# Tomcat + OSGi : No Catalina Service found

Tags: spring, tomcat, osgi, catalina, spring-dm

While trying to enable Spring DM with web support on virgo-tomcat-server-3.0.2.RELEASE, I get the exception:

```
ERROR WebExtender-Init
org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer
No Catalina Service found, bailing out
org.springframework.osgi.service.ServiceUnavailableException: 
service matching filter=[(objectClass=org.apache.catalina.Service)] unavailable
```

These are the bundles I added to the server:

- catalina.osgi-5.5.23-SNAPSHOT.jar
- catalina.start.osgi-1.0.0.jar
- spring-osgi-web-1.2.1.jar
- spring-osgi-web-extender-1.2.1.jar

Has anybody had this error before?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add catalina jar's in the pickup directory, since Tomcat Virgo Server has support for tomcat by default. You have to add catalina jar files to run Tomcat on Equinox OSGI server.

Spring dynamic modules has become a Eclipse  Gemini  Blueprint  project in late 2009. All new development (including for 2.x) is now hosted and released through the Eclipse foundation

Eclipse Gemini Blueprint can be considered Spring DM 2.x, the successor of Spring DM 1.x.

Tomcat Virgo Server has all the Blueprint Services(Spring DM) jar files inbuilt. You can refer [here](http://static.springsource.org/osgi/docs/2.0.0.M1/reference/html-single/#web%3aspring-mvc) on how to use Spring MVC with Gemini Blueprint Services.

The same [issue](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/842877/) is discussed in this forum.